# BadRequest: 400 Syntax error: Expected end of input

Tags: python, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to use `Dataframe` in SQL query to join with another table within google `BigQuery`, but I am getting a error I don't know why it is creating.

> BadRequest: 400 Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword TIME at [3:77]

This is my sql query and code I am using:

```
query = f"""
    SELECT *
    FROM contact c
    JOIN {merged_contacts} m
    ON c.id = m.id
"""

merged = pandas_gbq.read_gbq(query, project_id=project_id)
merged.head()
```

but this gives an **error**.

Comment: How `merged_contacts` variable is defined in your code ?

Comment: Yes it is. its a dataframe

Answer (score 2):

You cannot join the BigQuery Table and Dataframe. You could only join BigQuery to BigQuery and Dataframe to Dataframe.
You've mentioned `merged_contacts` is a Dataframe.
In your query, you're trying to join the BigQuery Table `contact` with Dataframe `merged_contacts` ID column.

You can first make your `contact` table to a Dataframe then join both Dataframe `m` and `c`

Here's an example of how to join table Dataframe to Dataframe:

```
sql = """
    SELECT name,year
    FROM bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current p
    LIMIT 100
"""

df = pandas.read_gbq(sql, dialect='standard')
print(df)

sql_2 = f"""
    SELECT name,gender
    FROM bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current p
    LIMIT 100
"""
df_2 = pandas.read_gbq(sql_2, dialect='standard')
print(df_2)

print(df.set_index('name').join(df_2.set_index('name')))
```

**Output:**

[image]